# Latest ExtentReports maven dependency for selenium

Tags: selenium, cucumber, report, extent

I have added this in my POM file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5</version>
</dependency>
```

It is not working for my project.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this strings in pom.xml:

```
<properties>
    <selenium.version>3.0.5</selenium.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Your string `<artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>` probably should be writing earler in another block - it is not dependency, it is the Name of your Project.